# Assigning a variable as color in a multicurve histogram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, colormap

I am trying to create a figure in which the intensity of a color in a colormap shows a variable. Each variable in X1 is a histogram, and I plot all of them in one figure. If I choose "color=colors1" it works, but it's not normalized, and I cannot connect it to the colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm

colors=[-1.666,-1.51116,-0.72945,-0.32506,1.79657,1.46693,0.1277,0.0276]
X1 = [residues_38_41,residues_2_3,residues_21_23,residues_50_61,residues_27_28,residues_41_42,residues_28_32,residues_43_42]

plt.figure(num=3, figsize=(9.75, 12), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
a2=plt.subplot(111)
colors1=plt.cm.coolwarm([-1.666,-1.51116,-0.72945,-0.32506,1.79657,1.46693,0.1277,0.0276])
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(colors), vmax=max(colors))
scalarMap = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=colors1)
image=plt.hist(X1, linewidth=4, bins=600, histtype="step", density=True, color=scalarMap, alpha=1)
plt.colorbar(scalarMap,label=r"$\Delta\Delta$G")
plt.show()
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: array([[0.2298057 , 0.29871797, 0.75368315, 1.        ],
       [0.2298057 , 0.29871797, 0.75368315, 1.        ],
       [0.2298057 , 0.29871797, 0.75368315, 1.        ],
       [0.2298057 , 0.29871797, 0.75368315, 1.        ],
       [0.70567316, 0.01555616, 0.15023281, 1.        ],
       [0.70567316, 0.01555616, 0.15023281, 1.        ],
       [0.38366207, 0.51018342, 0.91783067, 1.        ],
       [0.26180536, 0.34648432, 0.79565778, 1.        ]]) is not a valid value for name; supported values are 'Accent', ...
```

Comment: Would love to help you, but I get `NameError: name 'residues_38_41' is not defined`. You need to provide the data!

Comment: X1 is a list of lists, so it could be replaced with random values:

X1=[[3,10.1,5.2],[4,9.1,4.2],[5,8.1,3.2],[6,7.1,2.2],[7,6.1,1.2],[8,5.1,0.2],[9,4.1,1.2],[10,4.1,1.2]]